# The class MatplotlibDrawer needs pylatexenc. to install, run "pip install pylatexenc"

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory, qiskit

I am using colab for qiskit and even after installing pylatexenc using pip this still comes as an error, I also used !pip.[Here's the full pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSpMe.png)

Answer (score 7):

I think that you probably need to restart the kernel in jupyter and rerun the notebook.

The way optional dependency detection looks like it is done there is that when the module is first imported it checks if `pylatexenc` is installed or not. If it's not installed it sets a flag to say it's not present. Then when you go to use a function in the module if that flag is set it raises that import error. Without restarting the kernel that flag will still be set so it doesn't check again if `pylatexenc` is installed again on the 2nd call.

Comment: If you want your kernel to be restarted by a python command use this: `import os` and `os._exit(00)`. This will crash the python kernel and (at least in Google Colab) it will be restarted automatically, BUT the changes in libraries that you made with `!pip` will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pylatexenc
using the following command.

```
pip install pylatexenc
```